# JS pass var between functions

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a dude, I want to pass a var between two functions... How I can do that?

For example my code is the next

```
      beforeedit: 

            function preditar(editor, e, eOpts) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            var hoy = new Date();

            dia = hoy.getDate(); 

            if(dia<10)
                {
                    dia=String("0"+dia);

                }

            mes = hoy.getMonth();

            if(mes<10)
            {
                    mes=String("0"+mes);

            }
            anio= hoy.getFullYear();
            fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
            //alert(fecha_actual);

            var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
            alert(mola);

            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
                 {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
                 }
                else{
                    e.cancel = true; //mo permite
                }

            }  else
            {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }

        },

         edit:

             function editar(e, context){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();

             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));


             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData
             });
         }
        }
```

I would like to pass for example the var mola to the edit function... thanks for all, I don't know how I can do that... I don't find any example in internet I only find to pass a var to a function but not between functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare it outside the functions.
Or return it from the first, and pass it to the second function.

Something like this maybe?

```
{
    mola: '',
    beforeedit:
    function preditar(editor, e, eOpts) {
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
        var hoy = new Date();

        dia = hoy.getDate();

        if (dia < 10) {
            dia = String("0" + dia);

        }

        mes = hoy.getMonth();

        if (mes < 10) {
            mes = String("0" + mes);

        }
        anio = hoy.getFullYear();
        fecha_actual = String(anio + "" + mes + "" + dia);
        //alert(fecha_actual);

        mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
        alert(mola);

        if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
            if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual) {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            } else {
                e.cancel = true; //mo permite
            }

        } else {
            e.cancel = false; //permite
        }

    },

    edit:

    function editar(e, context) {
        var record = context.record;
        var recordData = record.getData();

        recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
        alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));

        mola && alert(mola);

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
            method: 'POST',

            // merge row data with other params
            params: recordData
        });
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: I think it depends on the context of the code, as to what the best answer is.

Comment: @harsha well, it _could_ be expanded

Comment: @Antonis : Ah,that looks better! :-)

Comment: @harsha still, it's a stupid sample of code  =P
He can write it better depending on what he wants exactly.

Comment: just a moment, i dont understand anything jeje, would you like to pass the real code please? i only want to pass hte content of the var = 'mola' to the  function edit....

Comment: could somebody help me please.

Comment: I already gave you an answer. Did you try it? Do you have a jsfiddle with your code?